# A question related to the spectrum of Gelfand-Tsetlin Algebra

Tags: permutations, representation-theory, irreducible-representation

Let's take the chain of permutation subgroups $S_1=\{1\}\subseteq S_2\subseteq .....\subseteq S_n$,where $S_{i-1}$ sits inside $S_i$ canonically as the stabilizer of $\{i\}$.Then for this inductive chain of subgroups we define *Gelfand-Tsetlin algbera* to be the subalgebra of $\mathbb C[S_n]$ generated by $Z_1\cup Z_2\cup.....\cup Z_n$, where $Z_i=$ center of the group algebra $\mathbb C[S_i]$.It can be shown that this special sub-algebra can be generated by so-called *Young-Jucys-Murphy* (YJM) elements,which are defined as follows,

$X_i:=(1\ i)+(2\ i)+.......+(i-1\ i)$;by definition $X_1=0$.

In other words,our *Gelfand_Tsetlin algebra* $GZ_n=\langle X_1,X_2,......,X_n\rangle$.

Now,take a finite dimensional irreducible complex representation $V$ of $S_n$ and restrict the representation to $S_{n-1}$,then restrict to $S_{n-2}$ and so on until we get down to irreducible $S_1=\{1\}$ modules i.e. one dimensional subspaces. Then up to a scalar we can choose a basis for this one-dimensional subspaces. These basis are known as *Gelfand-Tsetlin basis* or $GZ$-basis for $V.$

We also know that, YJM elements and hence any element of $GZ$ algebra act diagonally on the $GZ$-basis. Now I have following two questions.

$(i)$ If $v$ is an eigenvector of every element of $GZ_n$, then how can we conclude that $v$ belongs to the $GZ$-basis of $V$?

$(ii)$ Let $u,v$ be two $GZ$-vectors. If $u$ and $v$ have same eigenvalues for every element of $GZ_n$,then can we say $u=v$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.